# Why the same Access Token works for Media but doesn't work for Feed?

Tags: c#, instagram, instasharp

I'm using [`InstaSharp`](http://instasharp.org/) to get all medias from my account. This code works without any error:

```
 var user = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Media.Authenticated(config, authInfo);
 var media = user.Popular();
```

Now if I do the same with `Users`:

```
var user = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users.Authenticated(config, authInfo);
var feed = user.Feed("self");
```

This returns:

> `OAuthParameterException:` The access_token provided is invalid.

Why the same *access token* works in one place but doesn't work in another?

---

**Note:** I'm passing all scopes (`basic`, `comments`, `likes`, `relationships`) while getting the access token.I have also tried with default (`basic`) and it didn't work either.

**Note2:** Since I'm trying this in a `ConsoleApplication`, the way I'm getting the access token is, generate the link, copy/paste to the browser, confirm the authorization and get it from url. I'm not sure it makes any difference but it's worth noting...

Comment: The Instagram API wants the request as: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/... Your API adds 'self' for you `var request = Request("self/feed")`; (line 87 `Endpoints.Users`). The params passed (`Feed(string maxId, string minId, int? count)`) are apparently the min and max feed ids to get. No idea why you dont get an error passing only 1 string param (unless I have dug into the wrong thing or you are using an old version?). The code on GitHub matches the docs including the Min Max ID portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out the problem. It seems that the generated link was requesting `code`, not `access_token`.So that's why it was invalid.

And I realized that I was using older version of `InstaSharp` even though I downloaded it from it's website. First, I installed the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InstaSharp/2.0.0-beta3) via `NuGet`. Then, I get the access token and the media like this:

```
var config = new InstagramConfig(clientId, clientSecret);
var AuthLink = OAuth.AuthLink(config.OAuthUri + "/authorize", 
                              config.ClientId, 
                              config.RedirectUri,
                              scopes, 
                              OAuth.ResponseType.Code);

var authInfo = new OAuth(config);

// get the code from the link then pass it to RequestToken
var response = await authInfo.RequestToken(code);
var user = new Users(config, response);
var media = await user.RecentSelf(count: 30);
```

And all worked very well.

Comment: where do you use `AuthLink`? and what is in the `code` object?

Comment: @JPHellemons I go to AuthLink manually via browser, then give permission to app. after that it redirects you to instagram with a code in the url. that's the `code`